# (20.04 LTS) The MESA drivers are stuck in "(Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.5"

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, opengl, amd-ryzen

So I have a driver problem. For some reason, the MESA drivers are like this:

```
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.5
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.5
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.5
```

This is the output after I executed `glxinfo | grep Mesa`
I even asked VALVe on Github with these drivers.
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/csgo-osx-linux/issues/2817

I don't know what else to say.
Any help is wanted.